# How do you trigger a build when you check in code using VSO and visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, build-server, automated-deploy

I am developing using Visual Studio 2013 with Visual Studio Online for source control. I want to prevent check-in if the build that is triggered is returned false. Using the steps below, don't see how the builds are happening and not sure how to enforce good check-ins?

I completed the following steps:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/build-your-app-vs

Comment: Are you using TFVC or git for your source control ?

Comment: I am using tfs as source control

Comment: Does your code reside on VSO/VSTS ? If yes, then there are two source control that are available on VSTS, they are GIT or TFVC, which one are you using ?

Comment: Meant TFVC, not git...yes VSO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using TFVC the. You would need to use Gated Build as the trigger. Unfortunately Gated Build has not yet been implemented on the new Build system and is only available on the legacy Xaml builds.

If you were using Git you could take advantage of the Branch Policies to require that a build succeed before a checkin was allowed through Pull Requests.

You can either change your source control to Git and use Pull Requests, or you could change your build system to the Xaml builds and use Gated Build.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!